# Improving ArcGIS for Desktop geocoding process?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I would like to improve my ArcGIS for Desktop geocoding process comparing the city names between  two shapefiles . First one Store_city_name (point) and the second is city_name_boundaries (polygons).

My method : After using spatial join tool in Arcgis, If the city names from store shapefile are not the same as polygon shapefile, I’m trying to improve by identifying the distance between the store location and the city XY coordinate where it should be.

Everything is working well while calculating the distance between the store location and the centroide of the right city.  But sometimes this distance is so high specially if the store was geocoded, for exemple, 20 meters outside the edge of the right city.

I would like to find the distance and the XY coordinates from the store location until the edge of the right polygon (city feature) - where the store should be.   Can anyone help me ?

Comment: To be able to comment upon an existing workflow we would need to see more precise details (tools and parameter values) of its steps.